# How to automatically update contents of an Ember Component

Tags: ember.js

I have a transactions component, that doesn't auto update when new a transaction is added to the model that supplies its context.

If I leave to another route and come back, it renders it?

**dashboard.hbs**

```
 <h3>Recent Transactions</h3>
 {{transaction-history transactions=transactions}}
```

**components/transaction-history.hbs**

```
{{#each transaction in transactions}}
<tr>
  <td>{{transaction.ref_number}}</td>
  <td>{{transaction.date}}</td>
  <td>{{transaction.recipient}}</td>
  <td>${{transaction.amount}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

**action method in my Dashboard Controller**

```
actions: {
  submitQuickSend: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.get('http://localhost:8080', {request: 'generic'}).then(function(response){

      App.Transactions.push(App.Transaction.create({
        id: '',
        foo: 'bar'
      }));

      self.set('transactions', self.get('transactions'));

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `DashboardRoute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is change push to pushObject

```
actions: {
  submitQuickSend: function(){
    var self = this;
    $.get('http://localhost:8080', {request: 'generic'}).then(function(response){

      App.Transactions.pushObject(App.Transaction.create({ // change to pushObject
        id: '',
        foo: 'bar'
      }));

      self.set('transactions', self.get('transactions'));

    });
  }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely not true. Ember can track when an item is added/removed from an array and when an item is changed. Check out this JSBin (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/furodaxo/1/). Calling `addGreen` will add an item to the existing array, but the template will still update.

Comment: You're right. The workaround I had stated before the edit was the one I used when I didn't use "pushObject" and would instead use the "push" method. Good catch

Comment: That's probably the issue. I forgot that `push` doesn't function the same as `pushObject`.

Comment: Yeah, I already had implemented something very similar, I've now written it up in jsbin.. still not working :/ http://jsbin.com/nemum/3/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
{{transaction-history transactions=transactions}}
```

to

```
{{transaction-history transactionsBinding="transactions"}}
```

Comment: Hi Chopper, unfortunately that caused an error: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed transactions

Comment: If you want to use a binding like that, you have to pass it a string that will resolve to a variable in its scope. So if he wrote `{{transaction-history foo=transactions transactionsBinding='foo'}}` that would work. But it really doesn't matter because the first is valid (and the preferred) syntax.